# Reading from socket in C giving weird output

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having trouble reading from a socket. The code I'm using is below, sometimes it works just fine, but at other times, it just prints some unreadable characters, or some random readable ones... is there a better way?

```
    char* answer = (char*) malloc(1024);
    int answerLength = 0;
    char prevChar = 0;
    char newChar = 0;
    while (answerLength < 1024 && read(sock, &newChar, 1) > 0 ) {

            if (newChar == '\n' && prevChar == '\r') {
                    break;
            }
            printf("%d\n", answerLength);
            answer[ answerLength ] = newChar;
            answerLength++;

            prevChar = newChar;
    }
    printf("%s\n", answer);
```

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions).  'magic' numbers like that '1024' should be #defined to greatly ease the burden of debugging and later maintenance.  The #define name (go programming style says: all caps) should be indicative of what the 1024 means

Comment: regarding this line: 'if (newChar == '\n' && prevChar == '\r') {'  the OS/compiler will handle the difference between OS line endings, (some OS use only linefeed, some OS use only carriage return, some OS use a multi char string.  The compiler will handle  the details, so the code only needs to use '\n'

Comment: suggest using calloc() rather than malloc, so the allocated memory is 'already' initialized to all ''\0' so there is no worry about adding a null terminator to the input string.  BTW: when answerLength is 1023, should stop, not add another char, as adding the char will result in the 'answer' buffer having no room for the NUL string termination char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your char array is not guaranteed to be null terminated. This means that the `printf` may print more than just what is in your array since it looks for a null termination to stop outputting characters.

You also don't initialise the allocated memory before using it, which is bad practice since the memory can contain random garbage.

To get the code to work better and hopefully fix your problem, you should do the following:

```
char* answer = malloc(1024 + 1); /* add extra byte for null terminator */
/* other variables the same */

memset( answer, '\0', 1024 + 1 ); /* initialise memory before use */
while (answerLength < 1024 && read(sock, &newChar, 1) > 0 ) {
    /* loop is the same */
}
printf("%s\n", answer);
```

There is also an argument in `printf` which will tell it to print a certain number of characters. Like so:

```
printf( "%.*s\n", answerLength, answer );
```

Comment: Please remove the cast from `malloc()`, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495)

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C must be null-terminated, which means they must have a symbol `\0` as the last character.

Since you don't guarantee that it will happen anywhere in your code, `answer` may be padded with memory garbage next to the data you read.

To make sure it won't happen, use:

```
answer[answerLength] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", answer);
```

Also, you could just `read()` the whole thing straight to `answer`, you don't need that pointless loop:

```
int len;
while (len = read(sock, &answer[answerLength], 1024 - answerLength))
    answerLength += len;
answer[answerLength] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", answer);
```

Comment: Agreed. It's important to remember that the memory returned from malloc will be filled with undefined contents; it's not zeroed unless the code explicitly zeros it, thus, since the code doesn't manually null terminate, the `printf` could print any amount of garbage at the end depending solely on what was in that memory previously.

Comment: Or don't use `printf()` but a function that takes the length as an argument, the key problem is that `printf()` needs to determine where the string ends, since it does not find `'\0'`, it keeps reading through the garbage...

Comment: @iharob: `printf()` *can* take the length as argument: `printf(%.*s\n", answerLength, answer)`

Comment: Your single `read()` isn't equivalent to the original - the original read up to the first `"\r\n"` sequence, 1023 characters or error (whichever happens first) , but yours just takes whatever it gets in one read, which might not include a `"\r\n"` sequence at all, or might include more than one.

Answer (score 2):

The data you read isn't terminated with a `'\0'` character, so you can't treat is as a string.